# Issue in incrementing numbers in Do while loop

Tags: c, loops, numbers, do-while

I'm learning and tinkering with the C programming language. Unfortunately, While learning and playing with the do-while loop, I'm confused. I wrote and ran a program to increment a variable from 1 to 100 with condition i<=100; the code ran successful, but when I changed the condition of the do-while loop to i==100, the output confuses me because only 1 is printed on the console. Please help.

The code below gives the expected output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int i=1;
    do{
        printf("\n%d\n",i);
        ++i;
    } while(i<=100);

}
```

The code below gives output 1.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int i=1;
    do{
        printf("\n%d\n",i);
        ++i;
    } while(i==100);

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: notice that in the second case, i is never equal to 100, so it starts as 1, increments to 2, checks if it's equal to 100 and then terminates

Comment: For do/while the loop continues as long as the condition remains true. With that in mind can you see what values of `i` result in a true condition for the first case vs the second case?

Comment: You would probably find your programs easier to understand if you run them line by line in a debugger while monitoring the values of all variables (including loop counters).

Comment: Read the code "aloud" then use common sense from there: "do loop while i is 100" Is i 100 at the end of the loop? No it is 1+1=2. Therefore, stop looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `do-while` loop always executes once and then checks whether the condition holds true. If the condition is true, the loop executes again and then checks the condition.

In your case, the mandatory first pass prints the value of `i` and then increments it. Next, the condition is checked `while(i==100)`. At this point, `i` is `2` and the condition fails resulting in the loop being terminated.

Answer (score 2):

The second one loops if `i == 100`. It is not the truth (as i == 1) on the first iteration and loop exits.